# access NSMutableDictionary property in block

Tags: objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, nsmutabledictionary

I want to save the UIImages into a NSMutableDictionary which is a property in the method of a block,

```
    __block UIImage *headImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    headImage = [self getImageFromURL:status.user.profile_image_url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [headImageView setImage:headImage];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:headImageView];
    });
});
```

When debugging the getImageFromURL I found every time the iconDict is empty, and the method returns before setObject:forKey.

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)imageUrl {

UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

if(iconDict)
{
    image = [_iconDict objectForKey:imageUrl];

    if (image) {
        return image;
    }
} else {
    _iconDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
}

image = [self loadImage:imageUrl];
[_iconDict setObject:image forKey:imageUrl];

return image;
```

}

What's worry about this?

Comment: Why allocate `headImage` and then assign it in the block?

Comment: Because the images may haven't loaded,it will get the data by url of images. It's more smoothly to process in another thread .

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to change the semantics of your code.  There is no reason to store a `UIImage` instance in the calling function, so just make it so that `getImageFromURL:` simply returns boolean success status.  If that is `YES` then get the images from `_iconDict`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    if ([self getImageFromURL:status.user.profile_image_url]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [headImageView setImage:_iconDict[status.user.profile_image_url]];
            [[self contentView] addSubview:headImageView];
        });
    }
});

...

- (BOOL)getImageFromURL:(NSString *)imageUrl {
    UIImage *image = [_iconDict objectForKey:imageUrl];
    if (!image) {
        image = [self loadImage:imageUrl];
        if (image) {
            if (!_iconDict)
                _iconDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];                    
            _iconDict[imageUrl] = image;
        }
    }
    return image != nil;
}
```